# Script to Download File from Android Browser

Tags: php, android, download, content-disposition

I am not a web developer by all means. But I am trying to help someone deliver a video from their server. Basically when the user clicks a button on the website, we want the user to be prompted to download the video. So after Googling for a while I figured out how to write a short php script using content-disposition:

```
<?php
$fn = 'videoFile.mp4';

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fn));
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fn);
readfile($fn);
?>
```

So the button on the website points to this script. PC browsers seem to start the download with no problem. But the main focus of this is for Android phones. When you click to download the file on the default Android Browser, it fails and all it says is "Download Unsuccessful".

Another thing is that on my computer (using Firefox), the download starts and at about 200MB, it just stops. It doesn't show any signs of failure, it just looks like it finished downloading. The actual file size is about 1GB.

I have played around with the content-type quite a bit, hoping that was the problem. I used "video/mpeg" and "application/force-download" and neither of them worked.

Is there something I'm not doing write? Could the 2 problems be related? Should I be going about this a different way? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android browser does not appear to like `Content-disposition:` and related headers. I recommend just a plain redirect to the file in question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually found that all we needed was to add/modify the .htaccess file with "<FilesMatch "videoFile.mp4$">
  ForceType video/mp4
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>". That may have been what you meant, I don't know much about the web stuff so I don't know the correct terminology. Thanks.